# How replace html in template angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable that stores data

```
this.storage = { decription: 'text <br> info \n' };
```

In html I bring it

```
<div> {{ ::$ctrl.storage.decription }} </div>
```

However, the text is displayed without any formatting, but I would like it to be like html, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to use  `ng-bind-html` you need to tell angular that the HTML content string is trusted to know more about this you can refer this [**article**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) in angular docs,so to that add below code in your JS

```
$scope.storage.description =   $sce.trustAsHtml('text <br> info \n');
```

But simply this line will throw you an error saying 'unknown provider' to use that you need to have `angular-sanitize.js` in order to inject `$sce` in your controller and `ngSanitize` in your angular module like  `var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']);`

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$sce){
   

$scope.storage = {};
  
$scope.storage.description =   $sce.trustAsHtml('text <br> info \n');
  
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>




<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
  
  
<div ng-bind-html="storage.description"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: $sce.trustAsHtml return TrustedValueHolderType, but me need html

Comment: did you try running the snippet ? just follow the steps in code snippet it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-bind-html="scopevar"**

in example:

```
<div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.storage.decription"></div>
```

further details can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: @splincodeweb-developer It's not that it's all gone, **$ctrl.storage.description** might be empty in the first place. Try putting **storage.description** instead of **$ctrl.storage.description**. Also make sure **storage.description** is initialized properly in **$scope** as **$scope.storage.description** in order for **ng-bind-html="$scope.storage.description"** to display as intended.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div ng-bind-html="ctrl.storage.description"></div>
```

Comment: Great it helps.

Answer (score 0):

either you can use

```
this.storage = { decription: $sce.trustAsHtml('text <br> info \n')};
and use ng-bind-html
```

or write a directive for this,

```
(function() {
    'use strict'; 
    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('dynamic', dynamic);

    dynamic.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function dynamic($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                    ele.html(html);
                    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

and it can use as

```
<div dynamic="$ctrl.storage.decription"></div>
```